# Icon rendering on OpenGL

Tags: opengl, graphics, icons, textures

I want to render an RGBA icon (for an UI) using OpenGL. First, I used gimp to scale the icon to a power of 2. Then, I have used lodepng to load the icon, and then I rendered it using OpenGL (icon texture uses GL_LINEAR and GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR). The icon is rendered, but it seems blurry.

I guess that this is due to bad pixel fitting. However, I don't know what can I do.

Edit: using a high(16x) MSAA resolves the problem, but the performance penalty is too high.

Edit2: I'm using this shader to sample the icon texture

```
#version 140
noperspective in vec2 pos;

uniform sampler2D tex;

out vec4 colorOut;


void main(void){
    vec4 v=texture(tex, (pos/2)+vec2(0.5));
    colorOut=vec4(v);
}
```

Comment: Extremely high MSAA probably isn't what's fixing this - MSAA does not increase the number of times a texture is sampled or a fragment shader is run per-pixel, but it might change the location that it's sampled at. You might try something really simple like a constant half-pixel offset first.

Comment: I know MSAA is not the solution. However, using a constant offset doesn't work.

Comment: What you showed there (`+vec2(0.5)`) is not a half-pixel offset, but a half-texture offset. To offset by half a pixel (texel, technically) you would need to know the dimensions of the texture. `+vec2(0.5)/textureSize(tex, 0).xy` should do that.

Comment: 1. do not scale the texture, just zero pad it to power of 2, but use only the used space from it. 2. use rendered  icon size [pixels] the same as the used area of texture

Comment: @ Andon M. Coleman I knew that. I try it, and it didn't work :(

Comment: @Spektre That solution works, but it is too inflexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andon M. Coleman solution just works (and it is very simple), but I wanted to scale the icon to a proper size at runtime.

My solution was to make several (8x8) texel fetchs per pixel, this is too slow for a real-time app, but since icon size doesn't change the result of this can be cached on another texture. Then, I just need to fetch a sample per pixel.

The results are not as sharp as the Andon M. Coleman solution, but it looks pretty nice.